# Neo4j Desktop 1.1.10 how to export cypher file?

Tags: neo4j

I have created a graph database within Neo4j Desktop (`version 1.1.10`)  I wish to export that as a Cypher file.

How do I do that? I can't see any command within the app for export a Cypher file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following the documentation here: [Neo4j - Export a (sub)graph to Cypher script and import it again](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/export-sub-graph-to-cypher-and-import/)

First, install the apoc procedure library, and add it into the plugins directory.

Second, run Neo4j as an administrator. If not, Neo4j doesn't have permission to write files.

Before starting Neo4j, edit the neo4j.conf file and add this line:

```
apoc.export.file.enabled=true
```

Then, start Neo4j, and in the Neo4j browser, execute the following command:

```
CALL apoc.export.cypher.all("export.cypher",{})
```

This will store the whole database in the file "export.cypher".